# Insert nested data into BigQuery using Golang

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I can insert a flat object into BigQuery using Golang - how I can insert nested data into a table?

My BigQuery schema looks like this (from the example):

```
[{
    "name": "kind",
    "mode": "nullable",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "fullName",
    "type": "string",
    "mode": "required"
  },
  { "name": "visit",
    "type": "record",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields": [
    {
       "name": "time",
       "type": "timestamp",
       "mode": "nullable"
    },
    {
       "name": "duration",
       "type": "integer",
       "mode": "nullable"
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

My first attempt to insert looked like this (example):

```
func ExampleInsert(f string,) {

  jsonRow := make(map[string]bigquery.JsonValue)

  bq, _ := bigquery.New(client)
  request := new(bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequest)

  rows := make([]*bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequestRows, 1)

  jsonRow["kind"] = bigquery.JsonValue(kind)
  jsonRow["visit_duration"] = bigquery.JsonValue(duration)

  rows[i] = new(bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequestRows)
  rows[i].Json = jsonRow

  bq.Tabledata.InsertAll(projectID, "visits", "visitsv4", request)
  ...
}
```

Which flattens and inserts without problems. I'm just using visit_duration

But, I need to loop through a slice and add to the visits record. I've tried to build a **visit** object (without a loop to test) and add that to the row but it's not inserting and I get no errors:

```
func ExampleInsert(f string,) {

  jsonRow := make(map[string]bigquery.JsonValue)

  bq, _ := bigquery.New(client)
  request := new(bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequest)

  rows := make([]*bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequestRows, 1)

  jsonRow["kind"] = bigquery.JsonValue(kind)

  visits := make([]*bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequestRows, 1)

  jsonVisit := make(map[string]bigquery.JsonValue)
  jsonVisit["duration"] = rand.Intn(1000)
  visits[0] = new(bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequestRows)
  visits[0].Json = jsonVisit

  jsonRow["visit"] = visits

  rows[i] = new(bigquery.TableDataInsertAllRequestRows)
  rows[i].Json = jsonRow

  bq.Tabledata.InsertAll(projectID, "visits", "visitsv4", request)

  _, err := Call.Do()
}
```

---[SOLUTION]----

As suggested in the comments, I have also tried creating a slice and then appending the visit:

```
var visits []bigquery.JsonValue
visit := make(map[string]bigquery.JsonValue)
visit["duration"] = rand.Intn(100)
visits = append(visits, visit)

jsonRow["visit"] = visits
```

I can confirm this does in fact work :) For those of you reading this, the reason it wasn't initially, even after adding a slice, was because I had copied the table. In doing so, I had also flattened the results. Watch out.

Comment: I am not a Golang expert, but `visits` should be a map of `bigquery.JsonValue`

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: `visits := make(map[string]bigquery.JsonValue)`

Comment: I am not sure why you have used: `TableDataInsertAllRequestRows` that should be only used one time for the payload descriptor.

Comment: And you are reusing the wrong `i` value also, `i` is different for `rows`, and a different must be on multiple `visits`.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thank you - let me try. I wasn't aware about the 'TableDataInsertAllRequestRows'. And yes, that's a copy paste error as I had a loop previously.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a nested array as such, don't I need to create a slice and then append to it? If I use the map, I don't see how to add multiple elements into it.

Comment: Go try slice and append to it.

Comment: Slicing and appending looks like it's working but it's not updating the table. I'm assuming therefore I have something wrong with the key "visit". Have checked my schema and that's defo it's name.

Comment: This looks ok now, you should have your data good. Streaming insert has a few minutes delay until it shows up in your table.

Comment: Yeah, it does look right but still no datas. If I resort back to visit_duration and remove the slice I see the table update almost instantly. Is jsonRow["visit"] = visits actually correct syntax. Somehow feels wrong.

Comment: OK. Awesome. Thanks for the help. Human error - when I copied the table to a new one, I didn't notice the option: 'Flatten results', The copy was therefore not taking the old schema.

Comment: That's cool, I posted an answer to summarize these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visits should be a slice of `bigquery.JsonValue` I am not sure why you have used: TableDataInsertAllRequestRows that should be only used one time for the payload descriptor.

```
var visits []bigquery.JsonValue
visit := make(map[string]bigquery.JsonValue)
visit["duration"] = rand.Intn(100)
visits = append(visits, visit)

jsonRow["visit"] = visits
```

ps. also make sure you have your schema flatten