# Does bigquery have a reflect API?

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I'm tryig to insert data and then query it back but I cannot figure out how to do that without to [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30397686/3257971) map field names to struct values. Is there any reflect based API working like encoding/json or google datastore?